# Is there a compendium of enlightenment stories (about Arhats and/or Bodhisattvas)?

Tags: enlightenment, books

If I'm getting this right it is/was customary to utter a poem shortly after realizing enlightenment. Are these verses and/or maybe stories and accounts surrounding these beings collected somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. For the Theravada tradition's stories of the elder monks and nuns, please see the following books of the [Khuddaka Nikaya](https://suttacentral.net/pitaka/sutta/minor/kn) (the minor collection):

- [Theragatha](https://suttacentral.net/pitaka/sutta/minor/kn/thag) (Verses of the Elder Monks) or [here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/thag/index.html)
- [Therigatha](https://suttacentral.net/pitaka/sutta/minor/kn/thig) (Verses of the Elder Nuns) or [here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/thig/index.html)
- [Thera Apadana](https://suttacentral.net/pitaka/sutta/minor/kn/tha-ap) (Past Life Legends of the Elder Monks)
- [Theri Apadana](https://suttacentral.net/pitaka/sutta/minor/kn/thi-ap) (Past Life Legends of the Elder Nuns)

For e.g. you can read the story of [Sunita the Outcaste](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/thag/thag.12.02.than.html) who became an arhat elder.

Comment: https://suttacentral.net/pitaka/sutta/minor/kn describes the latter two as "legends of" not "biographies of", I quote -- The “Legends of the Senior Monks” contains 563 stories in verse telling the past life deeds of various senior monks. It is a much later counterpart to the Theragāthā, referring to many of the same monks. But whereas the Theragāthā verses relate the monks’ practice of meditation and mindfulness in this life, the Legends typically relate how they became awakened in this life by making an offering a Buddha in the distant past...

Comment: ...  and making a dedication to be reborn so as to become awakened in the future. The “Legends of the Senior Monks” has as companion the “Legends of the Senior Nuns”. Both these are late texts, and lack counterparts in the northern canons.

Comment: @ChrisW Updated to "Past Life Legends".